# Calling method from another Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to save data from dataGridView to a database with Datasets.

In my main form Form1 i have this function:

```
public void SaveToDB()
    {
        aSH_PROD_ORDERSTableAdapter.Update(aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1);
    }
```

When i call this in Form1 it works just fine.

However when i call it from From2 with this.

```
 public void Savestuff()
    {
        form1.SaveToDB();
    }
```

It get an exception saying:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have this in each form also:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1;

 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DateTimePicker oDateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
    Form2 resultsForm;
```

all i am trying to do is save data in the dataGridView in Form2 to the database.

and i figured this would be the best way to do it.

any ideas?

Comment: You are probably not populating the `form1` field anywhere.

Comment: @ZoharPeled could you explain what you mean by that? i am a new..ish programer. Thanks.

Comment: Probably it's better to have a service class calling your `aSH_PROD_ORDERSTableAdapter` directly, rather than call `form1` in `form2`

Comment: You aren't setting form1 to anything

Comment: What is `aSH_PROD_ORDERSTableAdapter`?

Comment: Hang on, are you creating Form1 as an inner class within Form2?

Comment: don't do this. Move your business and data logic into a separate class, and call that class from both your forms, then you can re-use it. The form code should contain GUI logic only. Opening up another form just to execute a database method makes no sense..

Comment: Forms are just classes, not magic objects. In Form2, `form1` is not an instance of the open form. You need to reference the instance of the form that is open.

Comment: please do accept upvote if works for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use method for saving data than i suggest you make seperate class with the method for saving

Below is just example , you need something like this

```
public class DbCrud
{
   public bool SaveData(DateSet ds)
   {
     //create data adapter object with required connection information
     // and just call save here 
      sqlCnn.Open();
      sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn);
      adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
      adapter.Update(ds);
   }
}
```

in form1 class

```
private DbCrud dbCrud;
public form1()
{
 dbCrud =new DbCrud();
  dbCrud.SaveData(ds);
}
```

in form 2 class

```
private DbCrud dbCrud;
public form2()
{
 dbCrud =new DbCrud();
  dbCrud.SaveData(ds);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how this answers the question

Answer (score 0):

When creating the object of your Form1 try this.

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

You should not be getting the exception after this.

Answer (score 0):

Well from this view point, maybe try with some static property of your Form1?

Answer (score -1):

Try to do next:

```
public static void SaveToDB()
    {
        aSH_PROD_ORDERSTableAdapter.Update(aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1);
    }
```

Comment: Depending on if `aSH_PROD_ORDERSTableAdapter` is an instance-member of `Form1` this won´t compile at all. Your answer however assumes that `aSH_PROD_ORDERSTableAdapter.Update` is also static.